# My footer won't stay at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm new to using bootstrap 3 and having a hard time with my footer. So I'm using a sticky footer and trying to keep my footer at the bottom of my home page but it keeps moving up. How can I correct this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>The Portfolio of Jason Murray</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font awesome css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Default Theme css file -->
    <link id="orginal" href="css/default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!--=========== HEADER SECTION ================-->
    <header id="header">
      <!-- BEGIN MENU -->
      <div class="menu_area">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
          <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- LOGO -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jason<span>Murray</span></a>
          </div>

          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>               
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>                           
            </ul>           
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>     
        </nav>  
      </div><!-- END MENU -->
    </header>
     <!--=========== END HEADER SECTION ================-->

    <!--=========== MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->
    <div class="jumbotron">   
      <div class="image_opacity"></div>      
        <div class="container">
          <div class="caption">
              <h2>Front-End</h2> 
              <h2>Web Developer</h2>
              <p>Hi, I'm Jason Murray and I have a passion for building simplistic websites.</p>
              <a href="#" class="caption_btn">Recent Work</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--=========== END MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->

    <!--=========== FOOTER SECTION================-->
     <footer id="footer">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <div class="footer_left">
               <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Jason Murray Web Design</a>. All Rights Reserved</p>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
             <div class="footer_right">
               <ul class="social_nav">
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </footer>
    <!--=========== END FOOTER SECTION================-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%
}

body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a{ 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f2f2f;

}
a:focus{
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;  
}

h2 {
  color: #313338;  
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img{
 border:none;
}

/*--------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*--------------------*/

#header{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*--------.menu_area-------- */
.menu_area{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
.past-main {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding:6px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;

}
#navbar{overflow-x: hidden;}

.navbar-brand {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-brand > span {
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { 
  color: #2da2c8;
}


/*---------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - HOME */
/*---------------------*/
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../Images/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.image_opacity{
  background: no-repeat center center #242434;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.caption {
  margin-top: 17%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption > h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 90%;
}
.caption>p{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;    
}
.caption_btn{
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus{
  border-color:#2da2c8;
  color: #2da2c8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#footer{
  padding: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
.footer_left{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer_left > p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.footer_left > p a {  
  font-weight: bold;
}
.footer_right{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.social_nav{
  text-align: center;  
}
.social_nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.social_nav li a {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.social_nav li a:hover{
  color: #2da2c8;
  border-color: #2da2c8; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#footer{
  position: fixed;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/2nzqa6fr/

Answer (score 0):

footer navbar-static-bottom *if you want it to to stay on bottom of page*

footer navbar-fixed-bottom *if you want it to stay on bottom of viewport *

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this a bit. I pulled it from the Bootstrap 3 documentation.

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```